# Argparse: Multiple argument processing

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, function, argparse

I am beginner in argparse I have question that about as below code:

```
def (x,y,z,t):

......
def main():

    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description= "Get Mapped Single PDB File")
    parser.add_argument("-pdb", dest="pdbfile",
                       help="Single Template PDB File")
    parser.add_argument("-sf", dest="file_of_seq",
                       help="Reference Seq File",)
    parser.add_argument("-rid", dest="refseqID", nargs=2,
                       help="Reference Seq ID")
    parser.add_argument("-cid", dest="chainID", nargs=2,
                       help="Chain ID")
    args=parser.parse_args()

    get_mapped_single_pdb(args.pdbfile, args.file_of_refseq, args.rid, args.cid)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I wanna do multiprocessing or put two arguments(I don't know how do i call that) on the bash screen as below:

--python xxx.py -pdb abc -sf ghj -rid qwe bnm -cid jkl tyu

And "-rid"'s first argument should be related with "-cid" 's first argument
and "-rid"'s second argument should be ... something like ....

I tried many way but I couldn't figure out. Do you have any recommendation ?

Comment: what is an actual `-rid` or `-cid` argument value?

Comment: -rid is reference sequence id as P08293 , -cid is chain id to extract pdb file as A , B or C. I want to do this let assume that P08293 related with chain A and P09134 related with chain B. Do I have any chance to run like this ?  -rid P08293 P09134 -cid A B. I want run it once. And give me all result in different cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With that parser and command line I expect

```
args.rid  # ['qwe', 'bnm']
args.cid  # ['jkl', 'tyu']
```

Pairing the 1st, 2nd values etc is standard Python list handling.

When debugging I suggest doing a

```
print(args)
```

to see what the parser gives you.

What have you tried?  What are the problems?

---

```
Namespace(chainID=['A', 'B'], 
          file_of_seq='uniprot_Marc_Vidal.fasta', 
          pdbfile='1VLG_A_14-155::1VLG_C_18-159#1.pdb', 
          refseqID=['P02792_A96T', 'P02794'])
```

You can easily pair the two lists with the standard `for zip` syntax:

```
In [120]: for id1, id2 in zip(args.chainID, args.refseqID):
     ...:     print(id1,id2)
     ...:     
     ...:     
A P02792_A96T
B P02794
```

or index iteration:

```
In [122]: for i in range(2):
    ...:     print(args.chainID[i], args.refseqID[i])
```

Comment: Namespace(chainID=['A', 'B'], file_of_seq='uniprot_Marc_Vidal.fasta', pdbfile='1VLG_A_14-155::1VLG_C_18-159#1.pdb', refseqID=['P02792_A96T', 'P02794']). I would like to do when I run the script once, first chain A with P02792_A96T runs then B with P02794 runs.

Comment: I added an example of using `for ...zip` to pair list values.

Comment: Thank you for your interest but I have another problem as: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. Should i change my script or is there any way to use your script without list because nargs are creating list and my script not accept list objects ? Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us anything about what the script accepts.  The 2 arguments with `nargs=2` produce lists, the arguments produce strings.  You have handle them accordingly.